# Laravel livewire pagination js issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have a livewire component to render a search table with pagination. some search fields are created as sliders.

When I change the page, these sliders are not created again by jQuery.

Livewire Code:

```
class WarehouseSearch extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $minB;
    public $maxB;

    public function previousPage($pageName = 'page')
    {
        $this->dispatch('name-updated');
        $this->setPage(max(($this->paginators[$pageName] ?? 1) - 1, 1), $pageName);
    }

    public function nextPage($pageName = 'page')
    {
        $this->dispatch('name-updated');
        $this->setPage(($this->paginators[$pageName] ?? 1) + 1, $pageName);
    }

    public function gotoPage($page, $pageName = 'page')
    {
        $this->dispatch('name-updated');
        $this->setPage($page, $pageName);
    }

    public function resetPage($pageName = 'page')
    {
        $this->dispatch('name-updated');
        $this->setPage(1, $pageName);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $warehouses = Warehouse::findActive();
        if (
            !empty($this->minB) ||
            (!empty($this->maxB) && $this->maxB != '5000')
        ) {
            $warehouses->withWhereHas('detail', function ($query) {
                if (!empty($this->minB)) {
                    $query->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('rent_monthly', '>=', $this->minB);
                        $query->orWhere('partial_space_rent_monthly', '>=', $this->minB);
                    });
                }
                if (!empty($this->maxB) && $this->maxB != '5000') {
                    $query->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('rent_monthly', '<=', $this->maxB);
                        $query->orWhere('partial_space_rent_monthly', '<=', $this->maxB);
                    });
                }
            });
        }


        $warehouses->latest('id');
        $warehouses = $warehouses->paginate(10, ['*'], 'warehousePage');
        $this->dispatch('name-updated');
        return view('livewire.warehouse-search', compact('warehouses'))
            ->with('i', ($warehouses->currentPage() - 1) * $warehouses->perPage());
    }
}
```

view file code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="advance-filter mb-4 show">
                <div class="position-relative">
                    <h3 class="search-heading text-lg-center px-3">Advanced Search</h3>
                    <span class="toggle-filter d-block d-lg-none" id="toggleFilter">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars text-white"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                            <button class="accordion-button py-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                                aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                                Monthly Budget
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                            aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                            <div class="accordion-body py-2">
                                <div class="single-filter">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <input type="text" class="budget-slider" data-skin="round"
                                                data-type="double" data-min="0" data-max="5000" data-grid="false" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <label class="filter-label" for="">Min Budget</label>
                                            <input type="number" maxlength="4" value="0" wire:model="minB"
                                                class="budget-from w-100 range-value px-3 py-1" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <label class="filter-label" for="">Max Budget</label>
                                            <input type="number" maxlength="4" value="5000" wire:model="maxB"
                                                class="budget-to w-100 range-value px-3 py-1" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="warehouses-list">
                @forelse ($warehouses as $warehouse)
                    @include('warehouse.card')
                @empty
                    No warehouses found.
                @endforelse
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card border-0">
            {!! $warehouses->links('custom-pagination-livewire') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
   window.addEventListener('name-updated', event => {
                console.log('here', event);
                createRangeSlider($('.budget-slider'), $(".budget-from"), $(".budget-to"));
                createRangeSlider($('.rent-slider'), $(".rent-from"), $(".rent-to"));
                createRangeSlider($('.area-slider'), $(".area-from"), $(".area-to"));
                createRangeSlider($('.dock-slider'), $(".dock-from"), $(".dock-to"));
            });
```

What I want from this is to re create the sliders when i switch pages. I was thinking of doing this using parent class but I was unable to do the needfull.
Please provide some suggestions for the same.

Thanks in advance.